# What does のかもな mean at the end of a sentence?

Tags: grammar, particles

I played a game (visual novel for PS2) in Japanese. And I came across this sentence:

> でも、あの時の俺は、本当は違ったのかもな。。。

And I was wondering what the part after 違う(ちがう）means. I guess, that の may change it into a noun, but I am not sure at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Would you understand what ～のかもしれないな meant? This is a shortened version of the same thing, the の here being part of the のだ construction.